# Crossplatform Java framework

Tags: java, frameworks, cross-platform

I'm searching for java framework like **libgdx** (you create code and it can be used for android, web and desktop applications), but with more comfortable GUI creation tools (like QtCreator). Does something like this exist?

Comment: Errrm, Java with Swing/JavaFX?

Comment: [Or perhaps this?](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077750/core-java/java-desktop-development-with-qt-jambi.html)

Comment: Looks like you are asking for a frameowrk to do some work for you. These type of questions are off-topic here. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Thomas, so it'll be one project for all platforms(like in libgdx) or I'll have to write 3 projects?

Comment: @Shark, I heard it's not supported from 2010

Comment: JavaFX works for web and desktop out of the box, Android would need some more setup: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Building-JavaFX-Android-Apps